# Freestyle SVG Export. How to save meshes without background?

Tags: freestyle, svg

I'm trying to render a model using Freestyle and export it using Freestyle SVG Export. Unfortunately, when I export my model as SVG I get not only the selected mesh, but also the background of camera viewport.

[image]

[image]

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Why not adjust render resolution to match your desired render size?

Comment: Hey, that's a perfect solution! I was sure that only internal Freestyle settings could affect SVG outputs. Thank you.